# How to reset usage tips

Tags: settings

My wife requested that I set up her new phone for her, then explain to her how to use it.  Well, my phone is a Windows phone, and I've never used an Android before.  (You may begin your jeering.)

Anyway, I noticed that there were a lot of usage tips that kept popping up that would be good information for her.  Is there a way I can reset those so that she'll see them?

**Note:**  I do **not** want a factory reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really only 2 tool tips that you dismiss. You'd be better off finding a tutorial or video to teach her.